# Owl carousel is not resizing to setted options

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I am adding Owl Carousel item dynamically. It is adding in the normal way, but when I'm scrolling to second page to check added image, it is smaller (~30%in heigth) as it must be. If I resize browser, it goes to the right size.

```
  $(".all_diplomas").owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        margin: 15,
        responsive: {
            1000: {
                items: 4
            },
            1200: {
                items: 2
            }
        },
    });


$('input#generateInputsForDiplomas').on('click',function() {
var template = '<div class="item"> <div class="content_diplomas autoHeightClass"> <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="images/6.jpg"><i class="material-icons">search</i></a>' +
                   '<figure><img src="images/6.jpg" alt=""></figure> </div> </div>';

    $('.all_diplomas').trigger('add.owl.carousel', [template]).trigger('resize.owl.carousel').trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');

});
```

I tried to use resize method before/after refreshing carousel, but it doesn't work. Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Probably not the best way, but solved with calling the JS event of
>   resize, which does not produce any visual effect, but solve the problem as required.

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```